# Stake Pool Saturation and Rewards changes

Tags: daedalus, staking, yoroi

Problem Statement: Currently, when delegators delegate to a stake pool, it is done via Yoroi or Daedalus. However, if the stake pool becomes saturated or if the SPO changes the rewards percentage, the delegator would not be aware. Expecting the delegator to constantly check on these is also not entirely realistic, given that some just want to buy, stake and hold.

Question: How will existing delegators know if their stake pool is saturated or if the rewards allocated have changed, if they don't monitor it regularly?

Answer (score 1):

To receive notifications about the changes of the margin of a pool you can use the **ADApools.org application** (iOS/Android). You can find the pool that you delegated to and then by turning on the notifications, you can check "margin changed".
There are other notifications but not the one of a saturated pool. Maybe they will implement this in the future.

Another way to do what you asked is to use the [Telegram Bot](https://t.me/AdaPoolsOrg_bot), where you can add the pool that you want to monitor and receive notifications about changes, including the saturation of a pool.

Comment: The Telegram bot is an awesome tip. Thanks!